# How to make indefinite amount of buttons stay in the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have such a requirement that I need to put indefinite amount of buttons in the same line.

The button's width needs to be adaptable to different button amount.

Here is my original fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/zL7tU/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="container" class="btn-group">
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">1</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">2</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">3</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
</div>
```

**Additonal requirement:**
There will be no text on those buttons.In my case,each button represents a test case execution result.For example,green button for passed one,red button for failed one.I just need to see the change of color so that i can know if the test case is stable.

Probably, the button could be very small just like one vertical line.

Comment: Are the buttons allowed to be a fixed height?

Comment: Yes,it can be fixed...this is used to show the stability of one test case...in my mind,each button looks like a vertical line if there are enough buttons...Is there any other approach to implement this without using button?

Comment: @Marc Audet,in my real case,the parent div has fixed width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach that might do the trick.

I would not use button elements since button styling and dimensions can be browser dependent.

Start with the following HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="status-group">
       <span class="status-bar" title="Tooltip text..."></span>
       <span class="status-bar" title="Tooltip text..."></span>
       <span class="status-bar" title="Tooltip text..."></span>
       <span class="status-bar" title="Tooltip text..."></span>
       <span class="status-bar" title="Tooltip text..."></span>
       <span class="status-bar" title="Tooltip text..."></span>
       <span class="status-bar" title="Tooltip text..."></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and apply the following CSS:

```css
.status-group {
    display: table;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    width: 100%;
}
.status-group .status-bar {
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}
.status-group .status-bar:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I would not use the Bootstrap button group styling.

Instead, define a CSS table as the parent container `.status-group` and set `width: auto` so that the total width is that of the fixed-width layout containing block.

To display the colored status bar, define a CSS table-cell `.status-bar` and set a reasonable value for the height and the minimum-width.

In this case, the table-cells will all have the same width automatically determined by the table layout.  As you add more status bars, the width will shrink proportionately until it reaches the minimum-width limit (could be 1px).

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/G6Fz7/

Note: If you have only a few status-bar elements, the result will look like a series of wide rectangles, but you can play with the table width (auto instead of 100%) and experiment with the table-cell width to get a more pleasing result.

To add **tool-tips**, you can use the `title` attribute on the `span` element.  If you want something more elegant, you may need to use some tool-tip library, but it can be done.

If you want to use **button elements**, you need so adjust the mark-up as follows:

```
   <span class="status-bar">
       <button  title="Tooltip text...">1</button>
   </span>
```

Place the button as a child-element of the `span.status-bar` because `button`'s do not recognize the CSS table-cell display value.

Comment: Thanks marc,that's fantastic!!! BTW,how can i implement this that a tooltip will be popped up when the mouse hover over one of the span?

Comment: Do i need to include some tooltip lib to implement this?

Comment: why i use button in the first place is because that i can leverage the built-in tooltip attribute of button to implement this

Comment: You can use a `button` element if you place the button as a child of the table-cell `span` element.  The `button` elements will not recognize the table-cell display value so that is why you need the `span` as a wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Set display:flex to the btn-group class.

```
.btn-group {
    display: flex;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/zL7tU/2/)** or **[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/tVz7U3i80x)**

Comment: With this means, it will be overflowed when there are too many buttons and a horizontal scroll bar will be shown.

Is there any way to make the button width dynamic so that overflow would not happen?

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap , based on your code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="container" class=" row-fluid btn-group">
<button>1</button>
<button>20000</button>
```

This worked for me, using the 'row-fluid' it will put all components in a row.

Comment: Yes, I've tried...the components will be in a row...but there will be a scroll bar for those overflowed components...what i need is all the components could be placed in a fixed-width div and the width of components would be dynamically adjusted for different amount of buttons